# PHP session variable resets all the time

Tags: php, session, isset

I have website written in Yii framework(just worth mentioning it) which has a few views. And every single view includes the same session varible, which then checks if it is already set. If it isn't yet set do something, else don't. The problem is, when i set the variable, when I go to another view, it unsets automaticaly. Here is the example:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['cookieNotifier']))
{ ?>

<div id="cookies>
   <button style="margin-top:5px; margin-right:10px;" class="lelbutton" onclick="hideClick()"><b>HIDE</b></button>
</div>

<?php } ?>

<script>
function hideClick(){
   $( "#cookies" ).hide(); 
   <?php $_SESSION['cookieNotifier'] = 1; ?>
}
</script>
```

I set it with a default value 1, but after chaging the view it seems it unsets itself. Any suggestions?

Comment: I take it you've `session_start();` loaded in all pages using sessions?

Comment: I hope you are not relying on your button to set the session variable as it will be set (see the previous comment...) long before the javascript is run / the page is presented in the browser.

Comment: @fred actualy I don't know. It says it's initialised in the framework when the user opens the page.

Comment: @jeroen how do I fix that?

Comment: You would need to make an ajax call to change server-side variables when you page is already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think the same as Fred -ii- mentioned.

You could use the below piece of code for troubleshooting (simply add it to the top of your PHP code before anything happens).

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

The issue might be that the session is not always started, therefore it loses the $_SESSION[] values.

Answer (score -1):

You should try using the Yii equivalent for storing user session variables. Have a look at the documentation for the CWebUser. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#setState-detail

Your example and using CWebUser state:

```
<?php if(is_null(Yii::app()->user->getState('cookieNotifier', null))): ?>
    <div id="cookies>
        <button style="margin-top:5px; margin-right:10px;" class="lelbutton" onclick="hideClick()"><b>HIDE</b></button>
     </div>
<?php endif; ?>
    <script>
        function hideClick(){
            $( "#cookies" ).hide();
            <?php Yii::app()->user->setState('cookieNotifier', 1); ?>
        }
    </script>
```